# Property of ODE $y'=\sin(y^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(x)'=\sin(y(x)^2),\ x\in\mathbb{R}$ be given.

I want to show *without solving* that
$$y=const. \Leftrightarrow (y(0))^2=k\pi, \ k\in\mathbb{N}$$ 
and that $y$ is monotone.

The direction $\Rightarrow$ is clear. Now for the interesting part ($\Leftarrow$):

Since $\sin(y)$ is countinously differentiable (thus locally Lipschitz continous), I can show that every local solution is unique by Picard-Lindelöf Theorem. It follows that the solution must not intersect the lines $y^2=k\pi, \ k\in\mathbb{N}$ and lies between them. Now I am stuck, as I can not show that this already leads to a constant solution.

Comment: This is an autonomous equation, so you can treat it by looking for equilibrium points and thinking about their stability.  If $0<y^2(0)<\pi$, then $y'$ is positive and the trajectories must be increasing for all $x$, but can't cross the equilibrium point at $y=\sqrt{\pi}.$  so you can squeeze the solution at $y(0)=\sqrt{\pi}$ between increasing and decreasing trajectories.

Comment: Maybe I thought too complicated, but if the solutions are locally unique and I know that the value $k\pi$ is taken at $x=0$ while knowing that $k\pi$ is a solution for all $x$, they must coincide, correct? I think I overthought on this one...

Comment: You need to separate what exactly you want to show, it seems that your task description mixes two problems. The first you have solved, characterizing the constant solutions. Now it remains to show that non-constant solutions are monotone, which is a trivial consequence of the constant sign of $f(y)=\sin(y^2)$ between roots.

Comment: @LutzL So my argument in my first comment is correct for showing that the solution must be constant if the said value is attained?

Comment: Yes. Roots of $f$ produce constant solutions, and by uniqueness, as you said, any solution having a root as one value has to be constant all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, roots $f(y^*)$ of the right side of $y'=f(y)$ produce constant solutions $y(t)=y^*$.

Yes, by uniqueness any solution having a root $y^*$ of $f$ as one value has to be constant all along.

As this scalar function $f$ has infinitely many roots converging to infinity, any initial value (that is not a root itself) is between two roots, the corresponding solution is bounded above and below by the respective constant solutions and exists thus for all times.

As this is a scalar equation and $f$ is continuous, the values of $f$ between two roots have a constant sign, so solutions are either monotonically increasing or monotonically falling.

The left and right limits $x\to\pm\infty$ of any such solutions are the bounding roots of $f$, as the limits exist and $y'$ converges to zero.